# Why does the graph of $\sqrt[3]{x}$ look like that on GeoGebra although $x^3$ is a one-to-one function

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, inverse, inverse-function

why does the graph of $\sqrt[3]{x}$ look like this
[image]

and not this shouldn't it be the graph of symmetrical with $x^3$ around the line $y=x$ is there a restricted domain and why ?  [image]

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting the information that $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ looks like the first picture. There is no restricted domain, and it looks like the second picture.

Comment: It's a matter of convention. Usually radicals are defined only for non negative numbers

Comment: @Crostul Are you suggesting that the cube root of $-1$ is not defined?

Comment: @Luna145 I used geogebra to graph this

Comment: @YoussefMohamed then it was a design decision by the developers. This may have something to do with how roots are implemented in their code but mathematically there is no reason it should look like the first graph.

Comment: One way to check whether a software system is giving the correct answer for a problem like this is to open up a calculus or precalculus book, learn how to graph an inverse function, and then work the problem out for yourself.

Comment: @Crostul that only applies to even roots.  There is no reason you can’t take the cube root of a negative number.

Comment: @LeeMosher I would upvote your comment twice if I could.

Comment: @LeeMosher That's why I was suspicious about the answer in the first place

Comment: In complex numbers, $x^{1/3}$ has three values.  If your software uses the "principal value" to choose one: when $x<0$ then $x^{1/3}$ is not real.  So $(-1)^{1/3} = (1+i \sqrt{3})/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok turns out it's wrong it was a mistake from GeoGebra the actual graph is the 2nd one I used desmos and it gave me this [image]

which is the correct answer